# Create .bat file to deactivate device

Tags: windows, home-networking, batch-file

I'm not familiar with creating .bat files, but I want to create a file to deactivate/disable a network device

[image]

This is in win7.
I have googled some similar problems, but nothing to solve this.
pls help.

Comment: deactivate/disable a network connection or the actual device? What exactly is the model of that device? A modem? Router? WIFI? IF its just a network connection on a windows 7 computer then check here > http://superuser.com/questions/463096/change-dns-with-script/463110#463110 or here http://superuser.com/questions/620229/how-do-i-connect-to-internet-from-command-prompt/620236#620236

Comment: I think that device is a speedtouch router/modem. What are trying to disable? Is it the device or is it just the visibilty in windows? You might be able to write a .bat that connects through telnet or SSH to shutdown your router but that is beyond my expertise.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you might be able use [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/enabledisable-network-interface-via-command-line/17a21634-c5dd-4038-bc0a-d739209f5081) in a batch file.
I'm unsure if your router will show up though.

**Get NIC list and index number:**

```
wmic nic get name, index
```

**Enable NIC with index number: (eg: 7)**

```
wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=7 call enable
```

**Disable NIC with index number: (eg: 7)**

```
wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=7 call disable
```

---

**Here is a batch file provided on the above link (You may be able to change it to suit your application).**

```
@echo off
cls
goto Choices

REM use this command to determine what the adapter index number is
REM wmic nic get name, index


:Top
choice /c:123456
If ERRORLEVEL == 6 goto Enable_Wireless_Disable_LAN
If ERRORLEVEL == 5 goto Enable_LAN_Disable_Wireless
If ERRORLEVEL == 4 goto Disable_Wireless
If ERRORLEVEL == 3 goto Disable_LAN
If ERRORLEVEL == 2 goto Enable_Wireless
If ERRORLEVEL == 1 goto Enable_LAN
goto EOF

:1
:Enable_LAN
wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=9 call enable
goto :EOF

:2
:Enable_Wireless
wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=7 call enable
goto :EOF

:3
:Disable_LAN
wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=9 call disable
goto :EOF

:4
:Disable_Wireless
wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=7 call disable
goto :EOF

:5
:Enable_LAN_Disable_Wireless
wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=9 call enable
goto :4

:6
:Enable_Wireless_Disable_LAN
wmic path win32_networkadapter where index=7 call enable
goto :3


:Choices
echo 1 Enable LAN
echo 2 Enable Wireless
echo 3 Disable LAN
echo 4 Disable Wireless
echo 5 Enable LAN / Disable Wireless
echo 6 Enable Wireless / Disable LAN
goto Top


:EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Enabling or disabling a network device in the *Network Devices* list is identical to enabling or disabling it in the *Device Manager*. You can use the Microsoft tool [`devcon`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/311272) to do this from the command-line.

1. Download the file, extract it, and put it somewhere (we’ll use `c:\tools` for the example below).
2. Now you need to determine the device ID. You can do it in two ways:

   - With the *Device Manager*

     1. Open the *Device Manager* (`devmgmt.msc`)
     2. Expand the *Network adapters* branch
     3. Locate and select the device
     4. Open its *Properties* dialog (double-click or [<kbd>Alt</kbd>+]<kbd>Enter</kbd> or right-click→*Properties* or *Action*→​*Properties*)
     5. Switch to the *Details* tab
     6. Select the *Matching Device Id* field
     7. Copy the ID (e.g., `PCI\VEN_1337&DEV_2600&SUBSYS_DEADCAFE`)
   - With `devcon`

     1. Open a command-prompt
     2. Run this command:

        ```
        devcon findall * | find /i "speedtouch" > "%temp%\devcon.txt"
        ```
     3. Open the file `%temp%\devcon.txt` and find your device

        - If you don’t find your device, try leaving out the filter:

          ```
          devcon findall * > "%temp%\devcon.txt"`
          ```
     4. Copy the ID (you only need up until the end of the `SUBSYS` field)
3. Test it (replace the path and ID with your own, and make sure to put the ID in quotes):

   ```
   devcon disable "PCI\VEN_1337&DEV_2600&SUBSYS_DEADCAFE"
   ```
4. Copy it to a batch-file (make sure to include the path if you are storing the batch-file somewhere different than `devcon.exe`). For example:

   ```
   c:\tools\devcon disable "PCI\VEN_1337&DEV_2600&SUBSYS_DEADCAFE"
   ```

You can then create a shortcut to the batch-file and set it to run minimized. If you don’t need to run other commands (the batch-file only contains the single line), then you can make a shortcut to run the command directly and forgo the batch-file altogether.

You can also make a batch-file/shortcut to enable the device as well (writing one to *toggle* the device is a little more complicated). You can even use this to enable or disable other devices (years ago I wrote one to toggle my old gameport gamepad when running DOSBox to work around [a bug](http://www.vogons.org/viewtopic.php?t=5385#p38619)).

---

[image: Screenshot of NIC device ID from Device Manager]